# What is the direct object in "He gave her a kiss"?

Tags: indirect-objects, direct-objects

I understand that if you give something to someone, that "something" is the direct object while that "someone" is the indirect object.

However, I have a hard time believing "kiss" can be the direct object in "He gave her a kiss".

Comment: Why do you think a kiss can't be a direct object?

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically, there is no difference between "He gave her an apple" and "He gave her a kiss"?

"He" is the subject in both cases.

"Gave" is the verb.

"An appple" and "a kiss" are the direct objects. They are the things that are given.

And "her" is the indirect object in both cases. She is the person they are given to.

Comment: You make a good point. I think my issue with words like "kiss", "hug" or "look" was that they're usually verbs. I see where you're coming from.